# How to sort 10 most called numbers from the list of called numbers with counter

Tags: android, sorting

I am working on phonebook app in android which contains frequently called numbers activity too.I have got the list of numbers with the counter that how many times its have been called.But now i want only 10 most called numbers from that list.
Here is the working code:

I have sorted data using map.

Basically i wanted to sort the data by value which is counter of called numbers.

```
 ListView list_view2;
String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG};
ArrayList<Integer> listdata2;
ArrayList<Integer> key;
ArrayList<Integer> value;
int maxIndex = 0;
Integer val;

HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_frequently_called);

    list_view2 = findViewById(R.id.list_view2);
    listdata2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    getCallDetails();

}

@SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
private String getCallDetails() {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestContactsPermissions();
        return requestContactsPermissions();
    }


    Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    Integer number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);


    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        Integer callType = managedCursor.getInt(type);
        Integer callDate = managedCursor.getInt(date);
        Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        Integer callDuration = managedCursor.getInt(duration);

        Log.e("Phone number", phNumber + "");
        Log.e("call type", callType + "");
        Log.e("call duration", callDuration + "");
       // Log.e("call date", callDate + "");
        Log.e("call day time", callDayTime + "");

        String dir = null;
        int dircode = new Integer(callType);
        switch (dircode) {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                dir = "OUTGOING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                dir = "INCOMING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                dir = "MISSED";
                break;
        }

        if (map.get(phNumber) == null) {
            map.put(phNumber+"", 1);
        } else {
            Integer scount = map.get(phNumber).intValue();
            scount++;
            map.put(phNumber+"", scount);

            //Log.e("map values", map + "");
        }
    }
    managedCursor.close();

    //Log.e("map.keySet()",map.keySet().toString());

    HashSet<String> numbersset=new HashSet<String>(map.keySet());

    ArrayList<String> numbers= new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> counts= new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Iterator iterator=numbersset.iterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        String no = iterator.next().toString();
        numbers.add(no);
        counts.add(map.get(no));
        }

    Log.e("number count ",numbers.size()+"|");
    Log.e("count count ",counts.size()+"|");





    for (int i=0;i<counts.size();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<counts.size();j++){
            int t1=counts.get(i);
            int t2=counts.get(j);

            if(t1 > t2){
                for(t1=0;t1>=10;t1++) {
                    for(t2=0;t2>=10;t2++) {
                        int temp = counts.get(j);
                        counts.set(j, counts.get(i));
                        counts.set(i, temp);

                        String temps = numbers.get(j);
                        numbers.set(j, numbers.get(i));
                        numbers.set(i, temps);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

//Sorting data in reverse

```
    for (int i=0;i<counts.size();i++){
        Log.e("sort-"+numbers.get(i),counts.get(i)+"");
    }

    return sb.toString();
}

    private String requestContactsPermissions () {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, 1);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, 1);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: as i am new to collection i am not able to sort it.i have tried code by Tejas Pandya.that worked but i am getting only counter in reverse order and i want counter in reverse with its numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your count array.This will sort your `counts` array in `descending`order.

```
Comparator mycomparator = Collections.reverseOrder();

Collections.sort(counts,mycomparator);
```

now if you want to get 10 elements from your ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Integer> popular_counts= new ArrayList<Integer>();


for(int i = 0; i< 9; i++){
   popular_counts.add(counts.get(i));
}
```

`popular_counts` is your final ArrayList.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tejas Pandya  your code worked out for me.

Comment: i want numbers also with counter.

Comment: @wish i've demostrated a way . now you can do this same process for your number array also .

Comment: just check out the code.i am done with it using hashmap.

Answer (score 1):

You can create loop that will be 10 times and another one which will search every time for the biggest counter and add the coresponding number to the new list.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  // Exaple to show result
    ArrayList<String> number = new ArrayList<>();
    number.add("0521392");
    number.add("0521396");
    number.add("0521397");
    number.add("0521398");
    number.add("0521391");
    ArrayList<Integer> counts = new ArrayList<>();
    counts.add(10);
    counts.add(5);
    counts.add(6);
    counts.add(10);
    counts.add(7);

    for (String n : mostCalled(number, counts, 8)){   // Calling the function and printing the output  
        Log.i("go", "phone number: " + n);
    }
}

private ArrayList<String> mostCalled(ArrayList<String> number, ArrayList<Integer> counts, int howMuchNumbersToShow){   // function that get list of phone numbers and list of how meany times each number called and return the howMuchNumbersToShow most called numbers (who called the most times)
    if (number.size() != counts.size()){
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
    int biggerNumber = -1; // will store the current biggest number
    int lastBiggerNumber = 10000000;  // will store the last bigger number
    int biggerNumberPlace = -1;     // will store the place of the biggest number in the array
    ArrayList<Integer> biggerNumberLocationList = new ArrayList<>();   // will store all the places of the biggest numbers in the array

    if (howMuchNumbersToShow > number.size())
        howMuchNumbersToShow = number.size();
    for (int l=0; l<howMuchNumbersToShow; l++){
        for (int x=0; x<counts.size(); x++){
            if (!biggerNumberLocationList.contains(x))      // to get each number one time (help in case more then one phone number called the same amount)
                if (counts.get(x) >= biggerNumber && counts.get(x)<= lastBiggerNumber){
                    biggerNumber = counts.get(x);
                    biggerNumberPlace = x;
                }

        }
        lastBiggerNumber = biggerNumber;
        biggerNumber = -1;
        biggerNumberLocationList.add(biggerNumberPlace);
    }

    ArrayList<String> mostCalledPhoneNumbers = new ArrayList();
    int place_in_array;
    String phoneNumber;


    for (int f=0; f<biggerNumberLocationList.size() ; f++) {
        place_in_array = biggerNumberLocationList.get(f);
        phoneNumber = number.get(place_in_array);
        mostCalledPhoneNumbers.add(phoneNumber);
   //     Log.i("go", "place in array " + biggerNumberLocationList.get(f) + ", the phone number "  + number.get(biggerNumberLocationList.get(f)) + " called " + counts.get(biggerNumberLocationList.get(f)) + " times ");
    }
    return mostCalledPhoneNumbers;
}
```

It would be easier to use HashMap for this job or even  ArrayList<> of type object that stores string and int.

Comment: And Also thanks to @guy i have tried your code but there was some issue,but still i will try that out once again. Actually i am not cleared with collection part of java thats why i took help.

Comment: Can you post the issue?

Comment: yeaah sure..                                                                                      `(ArrayList<String> number, ArrayList<Integer>` here it is showing expression expected.on the same line after counts and after howMuchNumbersToShow its asking for ";"                                  
  .cannot resolve "size()" in if statement . `mostCalledPhonNumbers.add(number.get(biggerNumberLocationList.get(x)));` cannot resolve get.                                                    
 `return mostCalledPhonNumbers;`  require java.lang.String and found java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String> .

Comment: check this  out .

Comment: @wish I updated the  answer and add more lines so that it will be easier to get details about the crash.
Can you post the errors now?. If there is more than one please tell me where do you refer to the first and where to the second (could not understand in the last comment).

Comment: 3)`mostCalledPhonNumbers.add(number.get(biggerNumberLocationList.get(x)));` cannot resolve get.                                                                        
                                                                                                      4)return mostCalledPhonNumbers; require java.lang.String and found java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String> .

Comment: now i have given numbers to the errors.hope that will help you to find that out.i have given lines where is the error  generating and what kind of error it is showing.

Comment: 1)`private ArrayList<String> mostCalled(ArrayList<String> number, ArrayList<Integer> counts, int howMuchNumbersToShow){` showing expression expected.on the same line after `counts` and after `howMuchNumbersToShow` its asking for  the `;` .                            
                                                                                                    
 2)cannot resolve `size()` in if statement .

Comment: Are you pasting the function inside a class?? Can you post a picture of how you paste it?, this code compiles in my android studio.

Comment: You should copy this inside the class but no inside other functions like onCreate.

Comment: how to post image??i have passed that function inside the class but out side the another functions.

Comment: just check out the code.i am done with it using hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

after studying a lot i made this custom code .which worked perfect.i guess its lengthy.but still.again thanks to @Tejas Pandya and @guy.

```
 //putting above data into hashmap
    HashMap<String,Integer>  hm = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < counts.size(); i++) {
        hm.put(numbers.get(i),counts.get(i));
    }

    //create list from elements of hashmaps
    List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(hm.entrySet());

    //sort the list
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> stringIntegerEntry,
                           Map.Entry<String, Integer> t1) {
            return (t1.getValue()).compareTo(stringIntegerEntry.getValue());
        }
    });

    HashMap<String,Integer> temp = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
            for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> aa : list){
                temp.put(aa.getKey() , aa.getValue());
                Log.e("descending",aa.getValue()+"");
                Log.e("descending",aa.getKey()+"");
            }
                String temp2 = String.valueOf((list.subList(0, 10)));
    Log.e("final",temp2+"");
```